# Functions of GSM

Tags: gsm, robotics

I am currently working on an arduino project and wanted to use a GSM module. This is my first time working with a GSM module. So I had a few queries.

What can a GSM module sim900a do with arduino programming?

Also can it do the following:

1. Send sms when motion is detected by a PIR sensor
2. Send sms to only a particular group of cell phones.
3. Respond to a particular kind of sms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Send sms when motion is detected by a PIR sensor

**Yes**, write a function that does this. Basic support functions in libraries will help you send the sms and detect the PIR. You need to provide the logic.

> 2. Send sms to only a particular group of cell phones.

If the question is if the GSM module supports group send the answer is **no**. You will have to write a function that sends the SMS to each number in the group.

> 3. Respond to a particular kind of sms

**Yes**, again but now you have to write a function that parses incoming messages and does some actions (just as any input parse).

The answer to all these questions is **no** if the function is already available in libraries. The answer is **maybe** if someone has already done something similar.

Answer (score 2):

None of those things you ask are a function of the SIM900A GSM module.

The SIM900A GSM module is capable of sending and receiving text messages (SMS). What you do with those text messages, and what text messages you send to where is entirely down to your Arduino program.

What you are asking is like "Can this car drive from Manchester to Carlisle?" The car can be driven from place to place, but it's *you* that does the driving. So you should be asking "I have a car. Am I capable of driving it from Manchester to Carlisle?"

So yes, the SIM900A GSM module is capable of being used to achieve those three things you ask, but the real question is not can the SIM900A do them, but *can you program the Arduino to get a SIM900A to do them?* And the answer is "Yes, it is perfectly possible if you know how", and we can help you to know how when you start working on the project and come across some stumbling blocks in your programming.